# how to filter tweet of twitter based on date with logstash date filter plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

i want to filter tweet of twitter by date filter plugin of logstash, this is the field of of `"@timestamps": "2016-08-10T06:46:26.031Z"` which each tweet have now i want to filter at based on now date and time  if any one help me ?

her is my logstash config

```
input {
twitter {
consumer_key => "key"
consumer_secret => "consumer key"
oauth_token => "aut"
oauth_token_secret => "oauth token"
keywords => [ "afghanistan", "TOLOnews", "kabul", "police"]
full_tweet => true
}
}

filter {
  date {
      match => ["timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z"]
  }
}
output {
   stdout { codec => dots }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "10.20.1.168"

        index => "twitter-%+YYYY.MM.DD"
        document_type => "tweets"
    }
}
```

but this not work because it index most twitter of tweet

Comment: What happens when you do this? What do you mean by "it index most twitter of tweet" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ignore incoming logstash entries that are older than a given date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087807/ignore-incoming-logstash-entries-that-are-older-than-a-given-date) and [How to filter input data of logstash based on date filed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624141/how-to-filter-input-data-of-logstash-based-on-date-filed), this last one being from the same user