# How to filter input data of logstash based on date filed?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

here is my twitter input tweets

```
"_source": {
"created_at": "Wed Aug 10 06:42:48 +0000 2016",
"id": 763264318242783200,
"timestamp_ms": "1470811368891",
"@version": "1",
"@timestamp": "2016-08-10T06:42:48.000Z"
}
```

and my logstash config file which include twitter input `plugin` filter and output

```
input {
twitter {
consumer_key => "lvvoeonCRBOHsLAoTPbion9sK"
consumer_secret => "GNHOFzErJhuo0bNq38JUs7xea2BOktMiLa7tunoGwP0oFKCHrY"
oauth_token => "704578110616936448-gfeSklNrITu7fHIZgjw3nwoZ1S0l0Jl"
oauth_token_secret => "IHiyRJRN09jjdUTGrnesALw4DRle35WyX7pdnI3CtEnJ5"
keywords => [ "afghanistan", "TOLOnews", "kabul", "police"]
full_tweet => true
}
}
filter {
    date {
      match => ["timestamp" , "MMM d YYY HH:mm:ss", "ISO8601"]
  }
 }
output {
   stdout { codec => dots }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "10.20.1.123"
        index => "twitter_news"
        document_type => "tweets"
    }
}
```

I want to just get new tweets for example today date is 2016-11-16, then I just want to get tweets that have `@timestamp= 2016-11-16` not  `@timestamp= 2016-11-15` or past days tweets, but with this configuration i get past tweets as well, any one help me to how do this ?

Comment: Please show a few sample log lines and what result you expect.

Comment: my input data is from twitter, twitter stream API send me old data is well i have a field by the name of @timestamps, then i want to filter it based on date to just get new data

Comment: Are you using the `twitter` input?

Comment: yes i am using twitter input

Comment: Please help me it's urgent i get lots of data about 3GB each day i don't have enough storage

Comment: Perhaps you could explain how you want to filter your data? And the date filter plugin, as you did not read/understood the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html), take a string representing a date, the format of the date and stores a date in a field.

Comment: i have update my question now check it once please

Comment: I believe you'll find the answer to your question here: [ignore incoming logstash entries that are older than a given date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087807/ignore-incoming-logstash-entries-that-are-older-than-a-given-date/30092806)

Answer (score 0):

the idea here is to use ruby code in logstash config. 
I propose to use `timestamp_ms` for comparing date.

1. First need to convert `timestamp_ms` to integer
2. Add today timestamp in ms with ruby
3. Compare timestamps
   Here is an example:

   ```
   mutate {
       convert => {
           "timestamp_ms" => "integer"
       }
   }
   ruby {
       code => "
           t = Time.now
           today_ymd = t.strftime('%Y%m%d')
           today_timestamp_ms = DateTime.parse(today_ymd).to_time.to_i*1000
           event['@metadata']['today_timestamp_ms'] = today_timestamp_ms
       "
   }


   if [timestamp_ms] < [@metadata][today_timestamp_ms] {
   ## past days events
       mutate {
           add_field => { "test" => "past days events"  }
       }
   } else {
   # today events
       mutate {
           add_field => { "test" => "today events"  }
       }

   }
   ```