# logstash ruby to check logtime and drop event if the logtime is older than 2-3 months

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am parsing a log which doesn't have a complete timestamp (year is missing), and to avoid any date mistakes, need to get all latest log lines but drop lines which are beyond 2-3 months.

Have come up to this ruby code

```
code => "if ( Time.now.to_f - 10368000 ) < ( event.get('new').to_f )
         event.cancel
         end"
```

But the parsing starts from Jan 2021 and stops at Mar 2021. Currently, the last update in the log is Jun 21. Basically, the idea is to get all the latest log lines from the log file and discard any line which is old. Like, ignore all months before Mar and get the rest of the lines.

Please advise.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087807/ignore-incoming-logstash-entries-that-are-older-than-a-given-date), almost solves it.

Comment: What about you count the date differences, store it to a field.
logstash then comparing the field, if meet the condition use drop filter.